# What does the Bible say Christians should or should not do on the Sabbath?

Tags: ten-commandments, sabbath

Most of the Christians I know do whatever they like on Sunday: working at home, paid employment etc.

Is there any specific information in the New Testament that suggest what Christians should or should not do?

Are we supposed to obey the Ten Commandments? What does that mean for Christians?

The Ten Commandments (Deuteronomy 5 NIV) tells us to:

> 12 "Observe the Sabbath day by keeping it holy, as the LORD your God
>   has commanded you. 13 Six days you shall labor and do all your work,
>   14 but the seventh day is a Sabbath to the LORD your God. On it you
>   shall not do any work, neither you, nor your son or daughter, nor your
>   manservant or maidservant, nor your ox, your donkey or any of your
>   animals, nor the alien within your gates, so that your manservant and
>   maidservant may rest, as you do.

Comment: In fact this question is nicely answered [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/967/what-has-the-bible-said-about-appropriate-sabbath-day-worship). The last sentence of that accepted answer answers your question fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly answered in [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply), but I will repost the relevant parts.

> **Acts 15:28-29** (NLT)
>   28 “For it seemed good to the Holy Spirit and to us to lay no greater burden on you than these few requirements: 29 You must abstain from eating food offered to idols, from consuming blood or the meat of strangled animals, and from sexual immorality. If you do this, you will do well. Farewell.”

This combined with a part of Jesus' Sermon on the Mount makes it even clearer.

> **Matthew 5:17** (NIV)
>   17 “Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to **fulfill** them.

[Emphasis mine.]

Thus, Christians are no longer *required* to keep the Sabbath holy. But, it's still a VERY good idea.

Comment: Worth adding where Paul explicitly says that "some treat one day as holy, some treat all days alike".

Answer (score 5):

> **[Mark 2:27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+2%3A27&version=NIV) NIV**
>    Then he [Jesus] said to them, “The Sabbath was made for man, not man for the Sabbath.

The new Testament does not specify that there is anything we , as Christians, should do/not do on the Sabbath.
The Sabbath was made for us to rest. In Genesis it says that God rested on the seventh day,   we should likewise also take a day to rest.

Comment: If not directly commanded, it is *strongly* implied there should be worship on the Lord's Day, however ;)

Answer (score 2):

The Old Testament day of rest was a prefigure for the rest we have in Christ. As the author of Hebrews says, we "cease from our own works" every day (see Galatians 5:19-21), not just on a particular day of the week.

> **Hebrews 4:8-10** King James Version (KJV)
>   *For if Jesus had given them rest, then would he not afterward have
>   spoken of another day. There remaineth therefore a rest to the people
>   of God. For he that is entered into his rest, he also hath ceased from
>   his own works, as God did from his.*

Answer (score 2):

Christians have different views of the applicability of the sabbath.

Among those who think it is completely fulfilled and abrogated (e.g., [Tom Schreiner](http://thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/justintaylor/2010/10/14/schreiner-qa-is-the-sabbath-still-required-for-christians/), [D. A. Carson](http://thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/justintaylor/2010/10/14/from-sabbath-to-lords-day-a-biblical-historical-and-theological-investigation/), etc.), there are no restrictions.

Among those who think it is [still in force](http://thirdmill.org/answers/answer.asp/file/40010), opinions vary. [John Frame says](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0875527965) that the emphasis is on physical rest for you and those under your sway -- including family, employees, and workers at stores, though he suggests that food is a necessity *someone* must prepare and therefore eating out is not verboten. Hence, he suggests ordinary work (paid work, yard work, homework, etc.) and commerce/shopping should not be done (cf. [Neh. 13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Nehemiah%2013)). He believes the Bible permits non-commercial recreation, etc., though some stricter adherents to the [Westminster Standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_Standards) argue that it does not do so and that all of the sabbath should be given to study, prayer, and worship.

Answer (score 0):

In Colossians 2:16–17 the apostle Paul declares:

> Therefore do not let anyone judge you by what you eat or drink, or with regard to a religious festival, a New Moon celebration or a Sabbath day. These are a shadow of the things that were to come; the reality, however, is found in Christ.

We are no longer commanded to cease working on the Sabbath.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your answer, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for offering an answer. Can you provide any further Bible quotes and explanation to support it? Though your answer as it stands is fine, we do prefer somewhat longer answers here. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) Meanwhile, I do hope you'll stick around, and browse some of the other questions and answers here.

Answer (score 0):

**What does the Bible say Christians should or should not do on the Sabbath?**

There are two reasons that Christians are not required to observe the Sabbath.

The first is that it was given as a sign for Israel.

> Exodus 31:13  Speak thou also unto the children of Israel, saying,
>   Verily my sabbaths ye shall keep: for it is a sign between me and you
>   throughout your generations; that ye may know that I am the LORD that
>   doth sanctify you.

The second is that Christians are not under the law.

> Galatians 5:18  But if ye be led of the Spirit, ye are not under the
>   law.