# What does the bible say about sundays?

Tags: sabbath, sunday

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the Bible say Christians should or should not do on the Sabbath?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/what-does-the-bible-say-christians-should-or-should-not-do-on-the-sabbath)

In the Bible it says that the 7th day should be set aside and be holy. It is the day of rest. Does this simply mean that we are not allowed to do any work? What will happen if you do? Is this going against God's will?

Comment: I think the answer is probably covered in any of the following: [Why does Judaism celebrate Sabbath on Saturday and most Christians celebrate Sabbath on Sunday?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4) : [What does the Bible say Christians should or should not do on the Sabbath?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1322) : [What has the Bible said about appropriate Sabbath-day worship?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/967) : [Does it matter which day I celebrate Sabbath / Lord's day on?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2979)

Comment: Sunday = first day of the week. 7th = Saturday.